# HornetQ Queue Browser

Tags: jms, hornetq

I`m trying to look at the messages from a queue using a Browser.
Code is like:

```
javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup('java:/XAConnectionFactory');

javax.jms.QueueConnection connection = qcf.createQueueConnection('admin', 'admin'); // qcf.createQueueConnection();
javax.jms.QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
connection.start();

// It is a "special" queue and it is not looked up from JNDI but constructed directly
javax.jms.Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue)ctx.lookup('/queue/myQueue');

javax.jms.QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);

TreeMap<Date, javax.jms.Message> messageMap = new TreeMap<Date, javax.jms.Message>();
int counter = 0;

Enumeration<javax.jms.Message> enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
  counter++;
  javax.jms.Message message = enumeration.nextElement();
  messageMap.put(new Date(message.getJMSTimestamp()), message);
}

connection.stop();
ctx.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

The problem is that I always get only 1 message in the enumeration, even though when looking with the jmx-console and invoke listMessagesAsJSON I get tons of messages.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are hitting a bug as Sergiu said.

You could as a workaround define consumer-window-size on your connection factory differently. Maybe have a connection factory just for this use-case... or maybe upgrade the version of HornetQ.

Comment: I've answered my own question as per Justin Bertam's response in the community forum :) Thanks Clebert.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the consumer-window-size (like I did in my app) it seems that you can hit bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-691 .